# How to write string to file?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to figure out how to write a string to a file. The following gives me the error `format argument must be a string literal`:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{Error, Write};

fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let path = "results.txt";
    let mut output = File::create(path)?;
    let line = println!("{}", "hello");
    write!(output, line);
}
```

How can I write to a file from a string variable? If I change the follow line it works, but I can't figure out how to write to a file if the string is in a variable.

```
write!(output, "foo,bar,baz");
```

Comment: `println!`'s return type is unit; it will print the formatted string to stdout---perhaps consider `format!` instead?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Rust myself but I don't think `println!` returns a string. How about `let hello = String::from("Hello, world!");`

Comment: Thanks! I was misssing a 3rd argument to write! `write!(output, "{}", line);`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`write!` is a macro, similar to `print!`. It expects 2 or more arguments, the first being a writer, the second a format string (which must be a string literal) and after that zero or more expressions which will be placed into the placeholders in the format string.

So, you could combine both your last two lines like this:

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let path = "results.txt";
    let mut output = File::create(path)?;
    let line = "hello";
    write!(output, "{}", line)
}
```

Other methods to write to a Writer include calling [`std::io::Write::write_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_all), or to write a slice into a file directly you can use [`std::fs::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fs/fn.write.html).

Another thing to note: the `print!` macro does not return the output in a string, it prints the output to `stdout`. If you want to get the formatted result in a string, use the `format!` macro:

```
let my_string = format!("Hello {}", "world");
```